# ValueError: Unknown label type for classification_report

Tags: scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to evaluate the model for multiclass classification using classification_report module of the sklean package.

Dimensions of y_pred: (1000,36)
Dimensions of y_test: (1000,36)

I tried calling the classification_report on the 2 arrays i.e y_test and y_pred

```py
def display_results(y_test,y_pred,column_name=labels):
    print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred,target_names=labels))
```

With this code I get:

```py
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]), array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]))
```

I was expecting to get the Precision, Recall, F1 and the total average metrics for all the columns based on the labels passed to the function.

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: @MaximeKan sklearn version is '0.18.1'

Comment: can you please add the value for the variable `labels`

Comment: `classification_report` will not work with one-hot encoded labels - see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589669/confusion-matrix-error-classification-metrics-cant-handle-a-mix-of-multilabel/54595455#54595455); but  you seem to be in a *multi-label* setting, so it will not work here...

Answer (score 2):

For your error you need [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

Works best where you have multiclass-multioutput from a classifier

```
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target
type_of_target(y_test)
type_of_target(y_pred)

>>'multiclass-multioutput'
```

So, your solution is

```
print(classification_report(np.hstack(y_test),np.hstack(y_pred)))
```