# Calculate ROC curve, classification report and confusion matrix for multilabel classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, roc, confusion-matrix, multilabel-classification

I am trying to understand how to make a confusion matrix and ROC curve for my multilabel classification problem. I am building a neural network.
Here are my classes:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
ohe = mlb.fit_transform(as_list)
# loop over each of the possible class labels and show them
for (i, label) in enumerate(mlb.classes_):
    print("{}. {}".format(i + 1, label))

[INFO] class labels:
1. class1
2. class2
3. class3
4. class4
5. class5
6. class6
```

My labels are transformed:

```
ohe
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],...]]
```

Training data:

```
array([[[[ 1.93965047e+04,  8.49532852e-01],
         [ 1.93965047e+04,  8.49463479e-01],
         [ 1.93965047e+04,  8.49474722e-01],
         ...,
```

Model:

```
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])
H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

I am able to get precentages but I am a bit clueless in how to calculate confusion matrix or ROC curve, or get classification report.. 
here are the precentages:

```
proba = model.predict(testX)
idxs = np.argsort(proba)[::-1][:2]

for i in proba:
    print ('\n')
    for (label, p) in zip(mlb.classes_, i):
        print("{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, p * 100))

class1: 69.41%
class2: 76.41%
class3: 58.02%
class4: 63.97%
class5: 48.91%
class6: 58.28%

class1: 69.37%
class2: 76.42%
class3: 58.01%
class4: 63.92%
class5: 48.88%
class6: 58.26%
```

If anyone has some tips on how to do it or an example I would really appreciate it! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From v0.21 onwards, scikit-learn includes a multilabel confusion matrix; adapting the example from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix.html) for 5 classes:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
y_true = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
y_pred = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])

multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
# result:
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [2, 0]]])
```

The usual `classification_report` also works fine:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
# result
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00         2
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00         2
           2       0.50      0.50      0.50         2
           3       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
           4       0.00      0.00      0.00         2

   micro avg       0.75      0.67      0.71         9
   macro avg       0.70      0.70      0.70         9
weighted avg       0.67      0.67      0.67         9
 samples avg       0.72      0.64      0.67         9
```

Regarding ROC, you can take some ideas from the [Plot ROC curves for the multilabel problem](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#plot-roc-curves-for-the-multilabel-problem) example in the docs (not quite sure the concept itself is very useful though).

Confusion matrix and classification report require hard class predictions (as in the example); ROC requires the predictions as probabilities.

To convert your probabilistic predictions to hard classes, you need a threshold. Now, usually (and implicitly), this threshold is taken to be 0.5, i.e. predict 1 if `y_pred > 0.5`, else predict 0. Nevertheless, this is not necessarily the case always, and it depends on the particular problem. Once you have set such a threshold, you can easily convert your probabilistic predictions to hard classes with a list comprehension; here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np

y_prob = np.array([[0.9, 0.05, 0.12, 0.23, 0.78],
                   [0.11, 0.81, 0.51, 0.63, 0.34],
                   [0.68, 0.89, 0.76, 0.43, 0.27]])

thresh = 0.5

y_pred = np.array([[1 if i > thresh else 0 for i in j] for j in y_prob])

y_pred
# result:
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```