# Scoring metrics from Keras scikit-learn wrapper in cross validation with one-hot encoded labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am implementing a neural network and I would like to assess its performance with cross validation. Here is my current code:

```
def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
    precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))

def build_model():
    hiddenLayers = 1
    neurons = 100
    #hidden_neurons = int(train_x.shape[0]/(3*(neurons+1)))
    hidden_neurons = 500
    opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00005, amsgrad=False)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=neurons, activation="relu", input_shape=(15,)))

    model.add(Dense(units=2*hidden_neurons, activation="relu", input_shape=(18632,)))

    model.add(Dense(units=4, activation="softmax"))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['acc',f1_m,precision_m, recall_m])
    return model

x = df[['start-sin', 'start-cos', 'start-sin-lag', 'start-cos-lag', 'prev-close-sin', 'prev-close-cos', 'prev-length', 'state-lag', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']]
y = df[['wait-categ-none', 'wait-categ-short', 'wait-categ-medium', 'wait-categ-long']]
print(y)
#enforce, this is gone wrong somewhere
y = y.replace(False, 0)
y = y.replace(True, 1)

ep = 1

#fit = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=ep, verbose=1)

#pred = model.predict(test_x)

#loss, accuracy, f1_score, precision, recall = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=0)
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, batch_size=10, epochs=ep)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=classifier, X=x, y=y, cv=10, scoring="f1_macro", verbose=5)
```

I am using cross_val_score and tried to use a different metric in the function itself than accuracy but I get the error

> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets

and read here [confusion matrix error "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589669/confusion-matrix-error-classification-metrics-cant-handle-a-mix-of-multilabel) that I need to un-one hot encode the output, before scoring, but I couldn't find any way to do that with this function.

Is there a better way to implement multiple scorings than writing the entire process myself? As you can see I already have the scorings implemented and they work as expected during training, but I can't seem to extract the information because of cross_val_score

**Edit:**

I've ran just one iteration, with the following code:

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.1, shuffle=True)

train_x = train[['start-sin', 'start-cos', 'start-sin-lag', 'start-cos-lag', 'prev-close-sin', 'prev-close-cos', 'prev-length', 'state-lag', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']]
train_y = train[['wait-categ-none', 'wait-categ-short', 'wait-categ-medium', 'wait-categ-long']]
test_x = test[['start-sin', 'start-cos', 'start-sin-lag', 'start-cos-lag', 'prev-close-sin', 'prev-close-cos', 'prev-length', 'state-lag', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']]
test_y = test[['wait-categ-none', 'wait-categ-short', 'wait-categ-medium', 'wait-categ-long']]
test_y = test_y.replace(False, 0).replace(True,1)
train_y = train_y.replace(False, 0).replace(True,1)

ep = 500
model = build_model()
print("Train y")
print(train_y)
print("Test y")
print(test_y)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1, verbose=1)
pred = model.predict(test_x)
print(pred)
loss, accuracy, f1_score, precision, recall = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=0)
```

This yields the following output:

Train y

```
       wait-categ-none  wait-categ-short  wait-categ-medium  wait-categ-long
4629                 1                 0                  0                0
7643                 0                 1                  0                0
4425                 0                 1                  0                0
10548                1                 0                  0                0
14180                1                 0                  0                0
...                ...               ...                ...              ...
13661                1                 0                  0                0
10546                1                 0                  0                0
1966                 1                 0                  0                0
5506                 0                 1                  0                0
10793                1                 0                  0                0

[15632 rows x 4 columns]
```

Test y

```
       wait-categ-none  wait-categ-short  wait-categ-medium  wait-categ-long
10394                0                 1                  0                0
3804                 0                 1                  0                0
15136                0                 1                  0                0
7050                 1                 0                  0                0
30                   0                 1                  0                0
...                ...               ...                ...              ...
12040                0                 1                  0                0
4184                 0                 1                  0                0
12345                1                 0                  0                0
12629                0                 1                  0                0
664                  1                 0                  0                0

[1737 rows x 4 columns]
```

Pred

```
[[2.63620764e-01 5.09552181e-01 1.72765702e-01 5.40613122e-02]
 [5.40941073e-07 9.99827385e-01 1.72021420e-04 5.32279255e-11]
 [5.91083081e-05 9.97556090e-01 2.38463446e-03 1.01058276e-07]
 ...
 [2.69533932e-01 3.99731129e-01 2.22193986e-01 1.08540975e-01]
 [5.87045122e-03 9.67754781e-01 2.62637101e-02 1.11028130e-04]
 [2.32783407e-01 4.53738511e-01 2.31750652e-01 8.17274228e-02]]
```

I've copied the output as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experimenting with @desertnaut 's answer however because I have a multi class problem, I experienced problems not even with the loop itself but the `np.argmax()` line. After googling I did not find any way to resolve it easily so I ended up (on this user's advice) implementing CV by hand. It was a bit more complicated because I am using a pandas dataframe (and the code can definitely be cleaned up further) but here is the working code:

```
ep = 120
df_split = np.array_split(df, 10)
test_part = 0
acc = []
f1 = []
prec = []
recalls = []
while test_part < 10:
    model = build_model()
    train_x = []
    train_y = []
    test_x = []
    test_y = []
    print("CV Fold, with test partition i = " , test_part)

    for i in range(10):
        #on first iter that isnt a test part then set the train set to this 
        if len(train_x) == 0 and not i == test_part:
            train_x = df_split[i][['start-sin', 'start-cos', 'start-sin-lag', 'start-cos-lag', 'prev-close-sin', 'prev-close-cos', 'prev-length', 'state-lag', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']]
            train_y = df_split[i][['wait-categ-none', 'wait-categ-short', 'wait-categ-medium', 'wait-categ-long']]
            #terminate immediately
            continue
        #if current is not a test partition then concat with previous version
        if not i == test_part:
            train_x = pd.concat([train_x, df_split[i][['start-sin', 'start-cos', 'start-sin-lag', 'start-cos-lag', 'prev-close-sin', 'prev-close-cos', 'prev-length', 'state-lag', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']]], axis=0)
            train_y = pd.concat([train_y, df_split[i][['wait-categ-none', 'wait-categ-short', 'wait-categ-medium', 'wait-categ-long']]], axis=0)

        #set this to test partition
        else:
            test_x = df_split[i][['start-sin', 'start-cos', 'start-sin-lag', 'start-cos-lag', 'prev-close-sin', 'prev-close-cos', 'prev-length', 'state-lag', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']]
            test_y = df_split[i][['wait-categ-none', 'wait-categ-short', 'wait-categ-medium', 'wait-categ-long']]
    #enforce
    train_y = train_y.replace(False, 0)
    train_y = train_y.replace(True, 1)
    test_y = test_y.replace(False, 0)
    test_y = test_y.replace(True, 1)
    #fit
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=ep, verbose=1)
    pred = model.predict(test_x)
    #score
    loss, accuracy, f1_score, precision, recall = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=0)
    #save
    acc.append(accuracy)
    f1.append(f1_score)
    prec.append(precision)
    recalls.append(recall)
    test_part += 1
print("CV finished.\n")

print("Mean Accuracy")
print(sum(acc)/len(acc))
print("Mean F1 score")
print(sum(f1)/len(f1))
print("Mean Precision")
print(sum(prec)/len(prec))
print("Mean Recall rate")
print(sum(recalls)/len(recalls))
```

Answer (score 1):

`cross_val_score` is not the appropritate tool here; you should take manual control of your CV procedure. Here is how, combining aspects from my answer in the SO thread you have linked, as well as from [Cross-validation metrics in scikit-learn for each data split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201464/cross-validation-metrics-in-scikit-learn-for-each-data-split), and using accuracy just as an example metric:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np

n_splits = 10
kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True)
cv_acc = []

# prepare a single-digit copy of your 1-hot encoded true labels:
y_single = np.argmax(y, axis=1)

for train_index, val_index in kf.split(x):
    # fit & predict
    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, batch_size=10, epochs=ep)
    model.fit(x[train_index], y[train_index])
    pred = model.predict_classes(x[val_index]) # predicts single-digit classes

    # get fold accuracy & append
    fold_acc = accuracy_score(y_single[val_index], pred)
    cv_acc.append(fold_acc)

acc = mean(cv_acc)
```

At completion of the loop, you will have the accuracies of each fold in the list `cv_acc`, and taking the mean will give you the average value.

This way, you don't need the custom definitions you use for precision, recall, and f1; you can just use the respective ones from scikit-learn. You can add as many different metrics you want in the loop (something you cannot do with `cross_cal_score`), as long as you import them appropriately from scikit-learn as done here with `accuracy_score`.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still wanting to use `cross_validate` with one-hot encoded labels. This is a more scikit oriented way to go about it.

```py
X, y = get_data()
# in my application I have words as labels, so y is a np.array with strings
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(y)

# build a version of the scoring metrics for multi-class and one-hot encoding predictions
labels = sorted(set(np.unique(y_encoded)) - set(encoder.transform(['nan'])))

# these functions compare y (one-hot encoded) to y_pred (integer encoded)
# by making y integer encoded as well

def f1_categorical(y, y_pred, **kwargs):
    return f1_score(y.argmax(1), y_pred, **kwargs)

def precision_categorical(y, y_pred, **kwargs):
    return precision_score(y.argmax(1), y_pred, **kwargs)

def recall_categorical(y, y_pred, **kwargs):
    return recall_score(y.argmax(1), y_pred, **kwargs)

def accuracy_categorical(y, y_pred, **kwargs):
    return accuracy_score(y.argmax(1), y_pred, **kwargs)

# Wrap the functions abobe with `make_scorer` 
# (here I chose the micro average because it worked for my multi-class application)
our_f1 = make_scorer(f1_categorical, labels=labels, average="micro")
our_precision = make_scorer(precision_categorical, labels=labels, average="micro")
our_recall = make_scorer(recall_categorical, labels=labels, average="micro")
our_accuracy = make_scorer(accuracy_categorical)
scoring = {
    'accuracy':our_accuracy,
    'f1':our_f1,
    'precision':our_precision,
    'recall':our_recall
}

# one-hot encoding
y_categorical = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_encoded)

# keras wrapper
estimator = tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier(
                build_fn=model_with_one_hot_encoded_output,
                epochs=1,
                batch_size=32,
                verbose=1)

# cross validate as usual
results = cross_validate(estimator, 
                         X_scaled, y_categorical, 
                         scoring=scoring)
```