# Import Error: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting the following error message when trying to run this AlexNET python code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Local-Binary-Patterns\pyimagesearch\AlexCM.py", line 6, in <module>
    from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization' (C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Local-Binary-Patterns\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\normalization\__init__.py)

I then saw a post to change it to:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
but then get the following error message:

C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Local-Binary-Patterns\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users//PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/pyimagesearch/AlexCM.py
2022-04-15 15:57:39.219873: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-04-15 15:57:39.220029: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Local-Binary-Patterns\pyimagesearch\AlexCM.py", line 11, in <module>
    from image_dataset_loader import load
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'image_dataset_loader'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Below is the python code for better reference to the error message that I am getting:

```
 #Importing library
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
#from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

def fix_gpu():
    config = ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    session = InteractiveSession(config=config)

fix_gpu()

np.random.seed(1000)

#Instantiation
AlexNet = Sequential()

#1st Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(227,227,3), kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
AlexNet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))

#2nd Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
AlexNet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))

#3rd Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))

#4th Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))

#5th Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
AlexNet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))

#Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
AlexNet.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(32,32,3,)))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
AlexNet.add(Dropout(0.4))

#2nd Fully Connected Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(4096))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
#Add Dropout
AlexNet.add(Dropout(0.4))

#3rd Fully Connected Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(1000))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
#Add Dropout
AlexNet.add(Dropout(0.4))

#Output Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(24))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('softmax'))

#Model Summary
AlexNet.summary()

# Compiling the model
AlexNet.compile(loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer= 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

from image_dataset_loader import load
#Keras library for CIFAR dataset
from keras.datasets import cifar10
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test)=load(path, [imgPath, testPath])
#(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test)=cifar10.load_data()

temp = []
for label in y_train:
    temp.append([label])
y_train = np.array(temp)
print('-------------------------4')
print(y_train)
temp = []
for label in y_test:
    temp.append([label])
y_test = np.array(temp)
print('-------------------------5')
print(y_test)



# print('-----train images-----1')
# print(x_train)
# print('-----train labels-----2')
# print(y_train)
# print('-----test images-----3')
# print(x_test)
# print('-----test labels-----4')
# print(y_test)

#Train-validation-test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# SPLIT IS CRITICAL
# 22 IMAGES, 0.045; 11 IMAGES, 0.09; 8 IMAGES, 0.12
x_train,x_val,y_train,y_val=train_test_split(x_train,y_train,test_size=.12)

#Dimension of the CIFAR10 dataset
print((x_train.shape,y_train.shape))
print((x_val.shape,y_val.shape))
print((x_test.shape,y_test.shape))

#Onehot Encoding the labels.
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels


#Since we have 10 classes we should expect the shape[1] of y_train,y_val and y_test to change from 1 to 10
y_train=to_categorical(y_train)
y_val=to_categorical(y_val)
y_test=to_categorical(y_test)

#Verifying the dimension after one hot encoding
print((x_train.shape,y_train.shape))
print((x_val.shape,y_val.shape))
print((x_test.shape,y_test.shape))

#Image Data Augmentation
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True,zoom_range=.1 )

val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True,zoom_range=.1)

test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip= True,zoom_range=.1)

#Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(x_train)
val_generator.fit(x_val)
test_generator.fit(x_test)

#Learning Rate Annealer
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
lrr= ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc',   factor=.01,   patience=3,  min_lr=1e-5)

#Defining the parameters
batch_size= 10
#CHANGE THE EPOCH NUMBERS
epochs=5
learn_rate=.001

#Training the model
AlexNet.fit(train_generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                      epochs = epochs, steps_per_epoch = x_train.shape[0]//batch_size,
                      validation_data = val_generator.flow(x_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_size),
                      validation_steps = 2, callbacks = [lrr], verbose=1)

#After successful training, we will visualize its performance.


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Plotting the training and validation loss

f,ax=plt.subplots(1,1) #Creates 2 subplots under 1 column

#Assigning the first subplot to graph training loss and validation loss
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['loss'],color='b',label='Training Loss')
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['val_loss'],color='r',label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
f,ax=plt.subplots(1,1) #Creates 2 subplots under 1 column
#Plotting the training accuracy and validation accuracy
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['accuracy'],color='b',label='Training Accuracy')
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['val_accuracy'],color='r',label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


#Defining function for confusion matrix plot
def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title=None,
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    if not title:
        if normalize:
            title = 'Normalized confusion matrix'
        else:
            title = 'Confusion matrix, without normalization'

    # Compute confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

#Print Confusion matrix
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
    im = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set(xticks=np.arange(cm.shape[1]),
           yticks=np.arange(cm.shape[0]),
           xticklabels=classes, yticklabels=classes,
           title=title,
           ylabel='True label',
           xlabel='Predicted label')

    # Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
             rotation_mode="anchor")
    # Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
            ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                    ha="center", color="white"
                if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
    plt.tight_layout()
    return ax

np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

#Making prediction
y_pred=(AlexNet.predict(x_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")
y_true=np.argmax(y_test,axis=1)

#Plotting the confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_mtx=confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred)

#class_names=['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
CLASS_NAMES = [f.name for f in os.scandir(imgPath) if f.is_dir()]
class_names=CLASS_NAMES
print(class_names)


print("ypred\n", y_pred)
print("ytrue", y_true)

# Plotting non-normalized confusion matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes = class_names,title = 'Confusion matrix, without normalization')
plt.show()
# Plotting normalized confusion matrix
# plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes=class_names, normalize=True, title='Normalized confusion matrix')
# plt.show()
#Classification Metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, RocCurveDisplay
acc_score = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
print('\n\n\t\t  Accuracy Score: ', str(round((100*acc_score), 2)), '%')
prec_score = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'macro')
print('   Precision Score Macro: ', str(round((100*prec_score), 2)), '%')
prec_score = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'micro')
print('   Precision Score Micro: ', str(round((100*prec_score), 2)), '%')
prec_score = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'weighted')
print('Precision Score Weighted: ', str(round((100*prec_score), 2)), '%')
rec_score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'macro')
print('\t\t\tRecall Macro: ', str(round((100*rec_score), 2)), '%')
rec_score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'micro')
print('\t\t\tRecall Micro: ', str(round((100*rec_score), 2)), '%')
rec_score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'weighted')
print('\t\t Recall Weighted: ', str(round((100*rec_score), 2)), '%')
f_score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'macro')
print('\t\t  F1 Score Macro: ', str(round((100*f_score), 2)), '%')
f_score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'micro')
print('\t\t  F1 Score Micro: ', str(round((100*f_score), 2)), '%')
f_score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'weighted')
print('\t   F1 Score Weighted: ', str(round((100*f_score), 2)), '%')
print("Evaluation")
AlexNet.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size,verbose=1)
```

Any other information that is needed, let me know. I am also unable to print the output that is listed at the bottom of the code, so please let me know if I am missing anything with the print functions. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Probably the `image_dataset_load` script is missing or you are trying to run the script from somewhere else.

Comment: @Josh, Can you try to install `image-dataset-loader` as `!pip install image-dataset-loader` and the then import as `from image_dataset_loader import load` will resolve  your issue here. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2 -  So I did the pip install for image-dataset-loader and it says "Requirement already satisfied" and I also have the from image_dataset_loader import load listed at the top of the code.

I even did more research and added the following, but still got the same error message. I added: 

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

Comment: @TFer2 - Okay, so I was able to fix the code to make it work (kinda). Now I am getting this error message: 

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589669/confusion-matrix-error-classification-metrics-cant-handle-a-mix-of-multilabel

Comment: @Noltibus - Thank you for the link. I saw that before, but was unable to understand where to make that change on my code specifically. I am new to this, so kinda confused.

Comment: Please check how `y_pred` looks after this line `y_pred=(AlexNet.predict(x_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")` and what shape it has. For the confusion matrix to work, it needs to be a single value, no array or anything.

Comment: @Noltibus - I added the full code to this question, but I am unable to find anything showing an array. Can you assist?

Comment: Can you post the ouput of `print(y_pred)` and `print(y_pred.shape)` after the line `y_pred=(AlexNet.predict(x_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")`?

Comment: @Noltibus - This is what I get. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\Local-Binary-Patterns\AlexCM.py", line 261, in <module>
    confusion_mtx=confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred)

Comment: @Noltibus - 
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\Local-Binary-Patterns\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 307, in confusion_matrix
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)

Comment: @Noltibus - 

  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\Local-Binary-Patterns\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 93, in _check_targets
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets

Comment: Yes, I know but above that you should see the output of the two print statements in your log. Please try to get knowledge on how to actually use print statements and debugging of python in general first. Otherwise, there is no chance on helping you here.